# Can use Vue Bootstrap for PC website too?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to develop PC website using vue.js. Can I use Vue Bootstrap for my PC website?

Comment: Yes, here is the tutorial to get started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vu5QKn24uYs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop a PC website using vue.js